# SQL to determine if a job is 'Internal Only'

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working with recruiting data and want to produce output that will let me know if a job is 'Internal Only' (meaning it is only posted to an internal job board and not any external job boards. My desired output is one row per job with an internal_only column showing true or false.

I have a table that provides rows with a job id and a job board name and a 'live' column that represents if the job is posted to that site.

I created a data set at:
https://rextester.com/FHU87800

```
CREATE TABLE job_posts(
    ID INT NOT NULL
    , job_id INTEGER NOT NULL
    , job_board_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    , live BOOLEAN);
    
INSERT INTO job_posts(id,job_id,job_board_name,live) VALUES (1,20035,'internal',TRUE);
INSERT INTO job_posts(id,job_id,job_board_name,live) VALUES (2,20035,'company_external_1',TRUE);
INSERT INTO job_posts(id,job_id,job_board_name,live) VALUES (3,20035,'company_external_2',TRUE);
INSERT INTO job_posts(id,job_id,job_board_name,live) VALUES (4,20036,'internal',TRUE);
INSERT INTO job_posts(id,job_id,job_board_name,live) VALUES (5,20036,'company_external_1',FALSE);
INSERT INTO job_posts(id,job_id,job_board_name,live) VALUES (6,20036,'company_external_2',FALSE);
INSERT INTO job_posts(id,job_id,job_board_name,live) VALUES (7,20036,'company_external_3',FALSE);
INSERT INTO job_posts(id,job_id,job_board_name,live) VALUES (8,20037,'internal',TRUE);
INSERT INTO job_posts(id,job_id,job_board_name,live) VALUES (9,20037,'company_external_1',FALSE);
INSERT INTO job_posts(id,job_id,job_board_name,live) VALUES (5,20036,'company_external_2',TRUE);

SELECT *
FROM job_posts
ORDER BY 1
```

My desired output would show job_id 20037 as internal_only = TRUE and the other jobs as FALSE.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: 20037 has an external posting too.

Comment: I believe the 'live' value for 20037  company_external_1 = FALSE

This represents what I am trying to figure out. A job can have posts to internal and external, but I want to show internal_only = TRUE for those jobs where only the internal job board is 'live'. Apologies for not being more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter` clauses with `bool_or()` to achieve this:

```
with summarize as (
 select job_id, 
       bool_or(live) filter (where job_board_name = 'internal') as internal, 
       bool_or(live) filter (where job_board_name like 'company_external%') as external 
  from job_posts 
 group by job_id
)
select job_id 
  from summarize 
 where internal and not external;

 job_id 
--------
  20037
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anti-join to find the rows you want. For example:

```
select a.job_id
from (
  select distinct job_id 
  from job_posts 
  where job_board_name = 'internal' and live
) a
left join (
  select distinct job_id 
  from job_posts 
  where job_board_name like 'company_external_%' and live
) b on a.job_id = b.job_id
where b.job_id is null
```

Result:

```
job_id
------
20037
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ukA4DU4oPvGe7N2Fy3rKLe/0).

Answer (score 1):

You can Select the live internal jobs then use not exists to eliminate internal posting that also have an external posting.

```
select j.job_id
  from job_posts j
 where j.job_board_name = 'internal'
   and j.live 
   and not exists 
       (select null
          from job_posts j2
         where j2.job_id = j.job_id
           and j2.job_board_name != 'internal'
           and j2.live
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a case Query.

```
select id,job_id,job_board_name,live, case when job_board_name='internal' then 'TRUE' else 'False' end as internal_only from job_posts
```